# Delay ASG Scaling up trigger while machine boots

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

We have set up our Auto Scaling Group to scale up the number of instances when a certain load threshold is met.

The problem is that when the new instance has finished booting we have a bootstrap script that runs to configure the machine (the boot strap script launches puppet, which configures the machine accordingly).

During the run of this script (which can take a few minutes), the load on this machine is high, which causes the ASG to launch yet another machine, which in turn causes yet another instance to get created, etc. etc.

Is there a way to tell the ASG not to start collecting metrics from this machine until x amount of time has gone by (or better yet, when the boot strap script is done)?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set the healthcheckgraceperiod higher:

> Length of time in seconds after a new Amazon EC2 instance comes into service that Auto Scaling starts checking its health. During this time any health check failure for the that instance is ignored.
>
> This is required if you are adding ELB health check. Frequently, new instances need to warm up, briefly, before they can pass a health check. To provide ample warm-up time, set the health check grace period of the group to match the expected startup period of your application.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/API_CreateAutoScalingGroup.html

Comment: Looks like healthcheckgraceperiod does not delay the ASG from creating new instance... it only delays the instance from being attached to the ELB.  I haven't tested it myself, but that's what my colleagues say is happening.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, there is such a setting for scaling policies: [Instance warm-up](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-target-tracking.html#as-target-tracking-scaling-warmup)

It tells the autoscaling system not to take newly launched instances' metrics into consideration for a specified amount of time (the warm up time).

Since it defaults to the ASG's ["cooldown"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/Cooldown.html) time, there is correlation to that. You might need to adjust that as well to not trigger too many scaling activites just because your instances aren't ready yet. The documentation says it's not respected by target tracking or step scaling policies but I cannot confirm that in my tests and had to adjust it as well.